# Sharing to Tumblr using AngularJS ng-click is banned

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tumblr

So, I am trying to implement a share to tumblr button. When the button is clicked I want it to open a new window with the details of the current page etc. This is working fine for facebook, twitter, etc.

But when I do it for tumbler, when the new window gets opened by the user it doesn't load the normal share window, but redirects to this URL:

https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool/banned?

And displays the following text:

```
Not Available for Sharing
```

I am doing this new window stuff from an AngularJS controller called by the ng-click directive.

The controller code is:

```
$scope.openWindow = function() {
    window.open("http://www.tumblr.com/share", 'newwindow', 'width=400, height=400');
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
ng-click="openWindow()"
```

My website is just running on the development environment and running on the localhost. I was wondering if this has anything to do with it?

PS The example I used above is the simplest code in the documentation. In reality my url will have a few query parameters giving some more detail about the page - but it doesn't even seem to work for me for the most basic type!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems Tumblr is doing this only for localhost environments.  I have similar code and I get the same error only locally.  Try it on production or an actual domain.  It should work.

Comment: Cheers jedi - I suspected as much!